# Show that two power series have the same radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Show that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_{n}x^{n}}$ has the same radius of convergence as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_{n+m}x^{n}}$ for any positive integer $m$.

Should I use the Ratio Test? Or do I use induction?

Comment: Well, how are you defining the radius of convergence? Because if you use $r=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}1/\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$ then it follows readily.

Comment: Replace $x_n$ by $x^n$, twice. And perhaps explain really what you tried to solve this (say, when you mention induction, which induction did you try and where did it go astray?).

Comment: Hint: the power series $\sum_{n\ge0}c_nx^n$ and $x\sum_{n\ge0}c_nx^n$ have the same radius of convergence.

Comment: @egreg: How do you prove this hint?

Comment: @Freeze Let us give the OP a little time to think about egreg's hint, shall we? It is pretty easy, though, as you're multiplying a power series by a $\;C^\infty\;$ function.

Comment: @Freeze_S One converges if and only if the other one does.

Comment: @egreg: One direction is fine but the other one was struggling me...

Comment: @Freeze_S Multiplying a series by a nonzero constant doesn't change its character and, of course, you can assume $x\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence $R$ can be characterized as follows:

1. If $|x|<R$, then the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}c_nx^n$ converges
2. If $|x|>R$, then the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}c_nx^n$ does not converge

Let's put aside the cases $R=0$ and $R=\infty$, for the moment.

There is no problem with convergence at $0$, so we can assume $x\ne0$.

Suppose $|x|<R$. Then the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}c_nx^n$ converges, so also
$$
\sum_{n\ge1}c_nx^n
$$
does and, by multiplying by $1/x$, also
$$
\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\ge1}c_nx^n=\sum_{n\ge1}c_nx^{n-1}=
\sum_{n\ge0}c_{n+1}x^n
$$
converges.

Conversely, if $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}c_{n+1}x^n$ converges, then also
$$
x\sum_{n\ge0}c_{n+1}x^n=\sum_{n\ge0}c_{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n\ge1}c_{n}x^n
$$
converges and so does $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}c_nx^n$.

Now you can start induction.

For the case $R=\infty$ it's the same, because it means that the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}c_nx^n$ converges for all $x$.

Do separately the case $R=0$.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, note that one has always:
>   $$\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n=0}^Nc_nx^{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{x}\left(x\sum_{n=0}^Nc_nx^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^Nc_nx^n\quad(x\neq0)$$
>   So all expressions give rise to identical series!

Now, let's show the equivalence:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\in\mathbb{C}\iff x\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\in\mathbb{C}$$
On the one hand one has for nonzero values:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\in\mathbb{C}\implies x\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\in\mathbb{C}$$
On the other hand one has for nonzero values:
$$x\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\in\mathbb{C}\implies\frac{1}{x}\left(x\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\right)\in\mathbb{C}$$
And the trivial case can be checked separately:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n0^n\in\mathbb{C}\iff0\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n0^n\in\mathbb{C}$$